# Pass ReactiveObject ViewModel between Android Activity in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, reactiveui

I use `ReactiveObject` as a `ViewModel` in `Xamarin.PCL`:

```
public class PlanViewerViewModel : ReactiveObject
```

Inside the `ViewModel`, there are a lot of `ReactiveUI` logic such as:

```
FilterIssueTypeCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<string, List<IGrouping<int, StandardIssueTypeTable>>>(
                searchTerm => 
                {
                    Func<StandardIssueTypeTable, bool> filterIssueType = d =>
                        string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.IssueTypeSearchQuery) ? true :
                        Contains(d.Title, this.IssueTypeSearchQuery) ||
                        Contains(d.Category.Title, this.IssueTypeSearchQuery) ||
                        Contains(d.Issues.Count().ToString(), this.IssueTypeSearchQuery);

                    return RealmConnection.All<StandardIssueTypeTable>().Where(filterIssueType)
                                          .GroupBy(g => g.CategoryId)
                                          .ToList();
                }
            );

this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.IssueTypeSearchQuery)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .Select(x => x?.Trim())
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .InvokeCommand(FilterIssueTypeCommand);

_groupedStandardIssueType = FilterIssueTypeCommand.ToProperty(this, x => x.GroupedStandardIssueType, new List<IGrouping<int, StandardIssueTypeTable>>());
```

In `Xamarin.iOS` development, I could easily pass the `ViewModel` between each controller using this code:

```
var finderController = segue.DestinationViewController as PVFinderTabBarController;
finderController.ViewModel = this.ViewModel;
```

I am wondering how could I do it in `Xamarin.Android`?

I know there are several ways to pass data between `Activity`:

- Pass it as a `string`, `int`, `bool`: This is what I am currently use
- Serialize the object into `JSON`: slow
- Implement `Parcelable` or `Serializable`: I don't want to use it because that means I need to copy my `ViewModel` into `Xamarin.Android` project.

If I do it that way, there is no point in using `ReactiveUI`.

I am thinking of using `Application` class in `Android` and create one instance of my `ViewModel` in it so every `Activity` could refer to that. Something like this:

```
[Application]
public class GlobalState: Application
{
    public PlanViewerViewModel viewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any other solution?

Comment: I'm still new to RxUI, but you could probably hack up a RxUI version of a View-based Navigation Service using Intent and looking at how [ MvvmLight accomplishes it - https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform (Android)/Views/NavigationService.cs ] You can additionally mix MVVMCross's ViewModel first approach for navigation and use RxUI for binding/rx/etc. Otherwise wait for ViewModel first approach to become reality: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1048